# Windows Phone System.XML.XMLException: Root Element is Missing

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, deserialization

Updated
I have a fairly large XML document that contains over 20,000 objects. All the sudden its throwing a System.XML.XMLException: Root Element is Missing.

Here are my code blocks:

```cs
    public async Task<int> readDatabase()
    {

        IsolatedStorageFile myFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        List<card> temp= new List<card>();
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<card>), new XmlRootAttribute("card"));
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(myFile.OpenFile("cards.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
        {
               cardList = (List<card>)s.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return 1;


    }
```

Example of my card object in XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <mtg_carddatabase>
    <bdd_date><![CDATA[5/1/2013]]></bdd_date>
    <bdd_version><![CDATA[1.00]]></bdd_version>
    <bdd_name>Magic the Gathering® Card Database</bdd_name>
    <bdd_editor>Wizards of the Coast LLC</bdd_editor>
    <sets>
    <set>
    <name><![CDATA[15th Anniversary]]></name>
    <code><![CDATA[15A]]></code>
    <code_magiccards><![CDATA[15ANN]]></code_magiccards>
    <date><![CDATA[00/0000]]></date>
    <is_promo><![CDATA[True]]></is_promo>
    </set>
    </sets>
    <cards>
    <card>

    <id><![CDATA[3064]]></id>

    <name><![CDATA[Urza's Engine]]></name>

    <set><![CDATA[AL]]></set>

    <type><![CDATA[Artifact Creature — Juggernaut]]></type>

    <rarity><![CDATA[U]]></rarity>

    <manacost><![CDATA[{5}]]></manacost>

    <converted_manacost><![CDATA[5]]></converted_manacost>

    <power><![CDATA[1]]></power>

    <toughness><![CDATA[5]]></toughness>

    <loyalty></loyalty>

    <ability><![CDATA[Trample£{3}: Urza's Engine gains banding until end of turn. #_(Any 
    creatures with banding, and up to one without, can attack in a band. Bands are blocked as a 
    group. If any creatures with banding you control are blocking or being blocked by a 
    creature, you divide that creature's combat damage, not its controller, among any of the 
    creatures it's being blocked by or is blocking.)_#£{3}: Attacking creatures banded with 
    Urza's Engine gain trample until end of turn.]]></ability>

    <flavor><![CDATA[#_"Humans and machines working together can be fearsome indeed"Arcum 
    Dagsson_#]]></flavor>

    <variation></variation>

    <artist><![CDATA[Greg Simanson]]></artist>

    <number><![CDATA[180]]></number>

    <rating><![CDATA[2.449]]></rating>

    <ruling><![CDATA[£10/1/2008 : If a creature with banding attacks, it can team up with any 
    number of other attacking creatures with banding (and up to one nonbanding creature) and 
    attack as a unit called a "band." The band can be blocked by any creature that could block a 
    single creature in the band. Blocking any creature in a band blocks the entire band. If a 
    creature with banding is blocked, the attacking player chooses how the blockers' damage is 
    assigned. £10/1/2008 : A maximum of one nonbanding creature can join an attacking band no 
    matter how many creatures with banding are in it. £10/1/2008 : Creatures in the same band 
    must all attack the same player or planeswalker. £10/1/2009 : If a creature in combat has 
    banding, its controller assigns damage for creatures blocking or blocked by it. That player 
    can ignore the damage assignment order when making this assignment.]]></ruling>

    <color><![CDATA[A]]></color>

    <generated_mana></generated_mana>

    <pricing_low><![CDATA[0,08]]></pricing_low>

    <pricing_mid><![CDATA[0,25]]></pricing_mid>

    <pricing_high><![CDATA[1,01]]></pricing_high>

    <back_id></back_id>

    <watermark></watermark>

    <name_CN><![CDATA[]]></name_CN>

    <name_TW><![CDATA[]]></name_TW>

    <name_FR><![CDATA[Locomotive d'Urza]]></name_FR>

    <name_DE><![CDATA[Urzas Maschine]]></name_DE>

    <name_IT><![CDATA[Motrice di Urza]]></name_IT>

    <name_JP><![CDATA[]]></name_JP>

    <name_PT><![CDATA[Engenho de Urza]]></name_PT>

    <name_RU><![CDATA[]]></name_RU>

    <name_ES><![CDATA[Ingenio de Urza]]></name_ES>

    <name_KO><![CDATA[]]></name_KO>

    <legality_Block><![CDATA[b]]></legality_Block>

    <legality_Standard><![CDATA[b]]></legality_Standard>

    <legality_Extended><![CDATA[b]]></legality_Extended>

    <legality_Modern><![CDATA[b]]></legality_Modern>

    <legality_Legacy><![CDATA[v]]></legality_Legacy>

    <legality_Vintage><![CDATA[v]]></legality_Vintage>

    <legality_Highlander><![CDATA[v]]></legality_Highlander>

    <legality_French_Commander><![CDATA[v]]></legality_French_Commander>

    <legality_Commander><![CDATA[v]]></legality_Commander>

    <legality_Peasant><![CDATA[u]]></legality_Peasant>

    <legality_Pauper><![CDATA[b]]></legality_Pauper>

    </card>
    </cards>
    </mtg_carddatabase>
```

The issue looks like its with my Deserializer but it worked fine up till last week. :(

Comment: And where is the root element of your xml?  xml documents have to have a single root element.  You might be able to get away with it treating your xml as a fragment, but I'm not sure if that would work in this case.

Comment: Indeed, in  you sample XML the root element is missing.

Comment: Its my first time working with an XML doc I created how do I set a root?

Comment: I don't see where you open the tags `</card>`, `</cards>` and `</mtg_carddatabase>` that you close at the end of the XML. In this case `<mtg_carddatabase>` would bee the root element.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the formatting issue. But that are there.

Comment: Have you tried running the file through a separate XML validator? (search online) The snippet you've posted of a sample of the data doesn't show the problem but the error is with the data you have that hasn't been shared. There is no way to provide an answer beyond make sure you have a valid XML document. If it worked last week then look at what has changed since then. You have the file under source control after all, don't you?

Comment: I will try that when I get home. I did find a sort of solution late last night. I had to change my reader to a somewhat less elegant reader but it worked fine after. I will post the code when I get back tonight for anyone who wants to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is definitely something wrong with the XML formatting. It passed the XML validator's, I used three different ones, but I still can not get the older code to work. I used my source control to pull back an older version and it still doesn't run. I am leaning towards blaming Visual Studio now, I am running the 2013 preview and that's the only variable I did not test. I do want to find a way to make the older method work so if anyone has something that hasn't already been tried happy to keep going. This method takes a significant longer time to load in terms of user experience. I did get it working. Here is what I had to resort to as far as reading the XML.

```
    try
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("cards.xml");
            var cards = from c in xdoc.Descendants("card")
                        select new card()
                        {
                            Nname = (string)c.Element("name"),
                            Nmanacost = (string)c.Element("manacost"),
                            Nset = (string)c.Element("set"),
                            Ncolor = (string)c.Element("color"),
                            Nid = (string)c.Element("id"),
                            Nability = (string)c.Element("text"),
                            Ntype = (string)c.Element("type"),
                            Npricing_high = (string)c.Element("pricing_high"),
                            Npricing_low = (string)c.Element("pricing_low"),
                            Npricing_mid = (string)c.Element("pricing_mid"),
                            Nartist = (string)c.Element("artist"),
                            Nrarity = (string)c.Element("rarity"),
                            Nback_id = (string)c.Element("back_id"),
                            Nconverted_manacost = (string)c.Element("converted_manacost"),
                            Nflavor = (string)c.Element("flavor"),
                            Ngenerated_mana = (string)c.Element("generated_mana"),
                            Nlegality_Block = (string)c.Element("legality_Block"),
                            Nlegality_Commander = (string)c.Element("legality_Commander"),
                            Nlegality_Extended = (string)c.Element("legality_Extended"),
                            Nlegality_French_Commander = (string)c.Element("legality_French_Commander"),
                            Nlegality_Highlander = (string)c.Element("legality_Highlander"),
                            Nlegality_Legacy = (string)c.Element("legality_Legacy"),
                            Nlegality_Modern = (string)c.Element("legality_Modern"),
                            Nlegality_Pauper = (string)c.Element("legality_Pauper"),
                            Nlegality_Peasant = (string)c.Element("legality_Peasant"),
                            Nlegality_Vintage = (string)c.Element("legality_Vintage"),
                            Nlegality_Standard = (string)c.Element("legality_Standard"),
                            Nloyalty = (string)c.Element("loyalty"),
                            Nname_CN = (string)c.Element("name_CN"),
                            Nname_DE = (string)c.Element("name_DE"),
                            Nname_ES = (string)c.Element("name_ES"),
                            Nname_FR = (string)c.Element("name_FR"),
                            Nname_IT = (string)c.Element("name_IT"),
                            Nname_JP = (string)c.Element("name_JP"),
                            Nname_KO = (string)c.Element("name_KO"),
                            Nname_PT = (string)c.Element("name_PT"),
                            Nname_RU = (string)c.Element("name_RU"),
                            Nname_TW = (string)c.Element("name_TW"),
                            Nnumber = (string)c.Element("number"),
                            Npower = (string)c.Element("power"),
                            Nrating = (string)c.Element("rating"),
                            Nruling = (string)c.Element("ruling"),
                            Ntoughness = (string)c.Element("toughness"),
                            Nvariation = (string)c.Element("variation"),
                            Nwatermark = (string)c.Element("watermark")
                            //Url = (string)c.Element("set").Attribute("picURL")
                        };
                            cardList = cards.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error = e.Message;
        }
        return 1;
```